# Laravel 4.2: how to include file from vendor to controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

so I am trying to include the `/vendor/phpexcel/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php` but I can't seem to access it through the Vendor folder.

> Failed opening required '/vendor/phpexcel/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\uhtv-admin\vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

isn't working because it defaults to the App folder. How can I get out of the App folder and into the Vendor folder where the IOFactory file is at. The error thrown is Failed opening required

> '/vendor/phpexcel/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\uhtv-admin\vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Actually, composer should do the autoloading for you. Run `composer dump-autoload` and then just use the class with the right namespace.

Comment: most of the files that gets installed by composer have the namespace already assigned into them ,so do just as @lukasgeiter said then go to the file u need and copy its namespace + the class name and `use` it in ur file.